# Passing parameters in a clickable UIabel

Tags: swift, uilabel, parameter-passing

I'm trying to make a clickable UILabel by following with this code:

```
let tap_plato = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.ale_plato1))

plato1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
plato1.addGestureRecognizer(tap_plato)

...

@objc
func ale_plato1(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){

let label = sender.view

print ("tapped!")

}
```

This works well. But I want to pass parameters to the function. Something like this:

```
let tap_plato = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MenuController.ale_plato1("parameter")))
plato1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
plato1.addGestureRecognizer(tap_plato)


@objc
func ale_plato1(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer, parameterRecived: String){

}
```

But I don't know how do that in swift 3...

Any help? Thanks you

Comment: I don't understand why you want to pass a parameter, I mean, what this is going to be? The text from label or what?

Comment: You can do `let label = sender.view as? UILabel` and then you can access the text, if that is the case from @RenataFaria's comment.

Comment: clickable UIlabel? You mean a button?

Comment: No, certain that the OP meant clickable UILabel...

Comment: I am talking with OP.

Comment: Well he wouldn't have clarified `Passing parameters in a clickable UILabel` in the question... Simple English clarification made in the question multiple times as well as Question Title.

Comment: I want to pass a parameter because it is a serie of labels that are generated automatically and I need to know what label is doing the function call

Comment: You can do it without a parameter, you could attribute a tag to each label

Comment: Yes that is from @RenataFaria comment. If you are adding the UILabel in the Interface Builder then you can set its tag from the identity inspector. Otherwise you can set an integer starting from 1 (NOT 0 since all elements have 0 as its default tag and that may cause conflicts) to what ever the number of labels you are generating. And then access the labels with their tags respectively

Comment: It's true, I've managed to solve it simply by adding a tag to the variable and then reading that tag in the function. It worked. Thank you very much to all !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you make your multiple `UILabel` set each label to a different tag.

```
for i in 0..<3 {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.tag = i

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    label.addGestureRecognizer(tap_plato)
}

@objc func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let label = sender.view as! UILabel // if you are SURE that your tap will be a UILabel
    if(label.tag == 0) {
        label.text = "This is label 0"
    if(label.tag == 1) {
        label.text = "This is label 1"
    }
}
```

Threw this up in a jiffy, hop over the syntax issues if there are any.

Here we can create labels with tags and apply the same tap to them. From there, we can check what tag it is inside the tap method and do something from there.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is the simplest and the one that has worked best for me. Thank you!

Comment: `UILabel` already has a tag variable. Don't add one yourself ;)

Comment: tag is limited to `Int`

Comment: Correct... and that's all the OP needs to check in the `if` conditions inside the tap button as well as setting inside the loop `label.tag = i` where `i:Int`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `tag` attribute for Int values, but if you want anything other than that:

Create a custom UILabel Class with a value variable.

```
class LabelWithValue : UILabel {
    var value : String = ""
}
```

Then you can use it as a normal Label

```
let label = LabelWithValue()
label.text = "bla"
label.value = "Anything"
label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
label.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGetText)))
```

Then you can get it's text and it's value.

```
@objc func handleGetText(_ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let label = sender.view as? LabelWithValue {
        print(label.text)
        print(label.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a fan of this method -- keep the sender as a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and try and optionally cast the sender to a `UILabel` and check the validity first. From there,  OP can access the text.

Comment: This also assumes OP wants to access `UILabel` variables and only those.

Comment: Actually, thanks, you're right, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sorry, that solution crashed my app too :(

Comment: what line is the crash @Mimmetico? Did you solve it?

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to adapt it to my code to see if I get it. I'm a bit of a rookie yet and I do everything very slowly. :)